# Finding the integral of $\int \sqrt {1 + {1\over 2x}} {dx\over x^2}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Find the derivative of the following:

$$\int \sqrt {1 + {1\over 2x}} {dx\over x^2}$$

I am new to antiderivatives, howeer, I know $dx$, but I don't know what ${dx\over x^2} $ means.

Also, Could anyone show me how to solve this question?

I would appreciate if the solution was by using **substitution**, so that for example,

$$\int2x\sqrt{1+x^2}dx$$
make $u = 1+x^2$, and $du = 2xdx$
$$= {2\over 3}u^{3\over 2}+C
\\ = {2 \over 3}(1+x^2)^{3\over 2} + C$$

Thank you!

Comment: Let $u = 1 + 1/2x \implies du = -1/2x^{2} dx \implies -2 du = 1/x^{2} dx$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\frac{dx}{x^2}$ is just $\frac{1}{x^2}\ dx$
Thus the integral is:$$\int \sqrt {1 + {1\over 2x}} {dx\over x^2}=\int {\frac{1}{x^2}\sqrt {1 + {1\over 2x}} dx}$$
Using substitution, $u=1+\frac{1}{2x}$, $du=-\frac{1}{2x^2}$, then $\frac{1}{x^2}=-2\ du$
So $$\int \sqrt {1 + {1\over 2x}} {\frac{1}{x^2}\ dx}=-2\int{\sqrt{u} \ du}=-\frac43u^{\frac32}+C$$
And you can take it from here.

Comment: @didgocks $du=-\frac{1}{2x^2}$, multiply -2 on both sides you get $-2\ du=\frac{1}{x^2}$, which is the element you need to substitute for. Then plug in the values of u and du correspondingly, you can get $\int{\sqrt{u} -2\ du}$, the -2 can be pulled in front of the integral since it is a constant